# Select column for each month AND column for year

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, pivot

I have a postgresql database and **want to display the following**:

```
------------select/display this----------------
Year  |Jan  |Feb  |Mar  |Apr  |May  |...|Dec  |
-----------------------------------------------
2014  |199  |188  |174  |121  |170  |...|200  |
2013  |160  |140  |160  |170  |160  |...|140  |
2012  |255  |270  |260  |270  |260  |...|140  |
```

---

and my table looks like:

```
table employeePlans 
-----------------------------------------
id  |month(date)|plannedHours |emplyee_id
-----------------------------------------
1   |2012-01-01 |255          | 1
2   |2012-02-01 |270          | 1
3   |2012-03-01 |260          | 1
4   |2012-04-01 |270          | 1
5   |2012-04-01 |333          | 2
..  |...        |...          | ..
9   |2014-01-01 |199          | 1
10  |2014-02-01 |188          | 1
```

Every month is unique and the day is the first day of the month (2014-05-**01**)
I actually use JPA and if i could query it with that and wrap it into my entity-class and display it in my JavaFX tableview would be even better.
JPA entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employeeplannedhours", uniqueConstraints
        = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"month", "employee_id"}))
public class EmployeePlannedHours implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//Types are actually JavaFX properties

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "month")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date month;

@Column(name = "plannedhours")
private BigDecimal plannedhours;

@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
private Employee employee;

public EmployeePlannedHours() {
}

//Getter and Setters
}
```

---

What I've come up with until now by reading up on pivot and crosstab is:

```
SELECT *
    FROM 
    crosstab('SELECT date_part('year', month)::double as year, 
                //???How can I get plannedhours for every month???, 
                WHERE employee_id = 1                   
                GROUP BY year
                ORDER BY year')
        As ct(year double, jan numeric, feb numeric, mar numeric, 
            apr numeric, may numeric, jun numeric, jul numeric, 
            aug numeric, sep numeric, oct numeric, nov numeric, 
            dec numeric)
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to display? Is it for one employee? Sum of plannedHours of all employees? And are you concerned with the looks (you need the answer to look the way you drew it, that is months as columns) or just the same data?

Comment: I need a column for the year and columns for every month. I don't wan't the sum of plannedHours. I will mark what I wan't to display bold (it's the first table, the one with the columns year, jan, feb...).  
If you don't understand the data. Look for instance at row 9 of employeePlans table -> plannedHours = 199 & date Jan 2014 which should be shown the select statement in row '2014' and column 'jan' with the value '199'  
Yes I wan't it only for one employee

Comment: It may not help, but what I would do in Oracle is `Group By Emp_ID, Year`.  In my `Select` I would create 12 columns, one for each month using the following: `Max(Case When to_char(date, 'MM') = '01' Then PlannedHours End) as Jan` and continue this for each month.  Additionally, I would display `EMP_ID, to_char(date, 'YYYY')` I don't know PostGrepSQL, but would imagine there are similar features.  If this works, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @Phillp It worked. Post this as an answer and I will accept it:  
`SELECT date_part('year', month) as year,
 Max(Case When to_char(month, 'MM') = '01' Then PlannedHours End) as Jan,
 Max(Case When to_char(month, 'MM') = '02' Then PlannedHours End) as Feb,
 Max(Case When to_char(month, 'MM') = '03' Then PlannedHours End) as Mars,
 Max(Case When to_char(month, 'MM') = '04' Then PlannedHours End) as April, 
 Max(Case When to_char(month, 'MM') = '12' Then PlannedHours End) as Dez
  from employeeplannedhours 
  WHERE employee_id = 1 
  group by year 
  order by year DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

i will use sql query and hope it will help you in postgresql

```
with g
as
( select datename(month,[month]) as Month, year(month) as Year,sum(plannedHours) as PlannedHours
  from employeePlans
  group by year(month),datename(month,[month])
)
select Year,[Jan],[Feb],[Mar],...[Dec]
from g
pivot(sum(PlannedHours) for Month in([Jan],[Feb],....[Dec])) p
```

the idea, to split the month field into Month Name and Year and you group by them on the planned hours, then you apply the pivot

why to apply the group? because your table might contains  for same month different employees

hope it will help you

regards